# How to get table name from column in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2, tablename

I need the DB2 SQL query to find the table/tables from column name. I have the column name but don't have table name which this column belongs to.

Comment: It is possible that multiple tables have a column with that name. Especially if the column name is for example "ID" or "LAST_UPDATED"

Comment: @crowne - Check the question please I have already mentioned table/tables.

Answer (score 14):

```
select TBNAME
    from sysibm.syscolumns
    where NAME = '<column name>'
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT tabname
    FROM syscat.columns
    WHERE colname = 'mycol'
```

Comment: Object names default to all upper case in DB2, but in case someone is deliberately using mixed-case names, consider using WHERE UPPER(colname) = UPPER('somecolumnname')

Comment: You should even consider not using UPPER in the right part of the condition, for performance purposes `WHERE UPPER(colname) = "SOMECOLUMNNAME`

Answer (score 6):

For DB2/AS400 users:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME 
    FROM QSYS2.SYSCOLUMNS 
    WHERE upper(column_name) = upper('[column_name]')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio Server Explorer, I found using the following worked the best:

```
SELECT       TABNAME
FROM         SYSCAT.COLUMNS
WHERE        COLNAME = 'NASR_DESC'
```

Visual Studio still formatted it, but the formatting inserted by Visual Studio still worked.

Hope this helps someone searching for a known column name in their IBM DB2 database using Visual Studio Server Explorer.